# how to pass parameter values to batchfiles

Tags: batch-file

I have a bacthfile & I want to pass parameter values, how can I do it ?

```
@echo off
ECHO Param1: Database Name: %1
ECHO Param2: Datasource : %2
ECHO Param3: DB User Id: %3
ECHO Param4: Password: %4

SET DBNAME=%1
SET DBSERVER=%2
SET DBUSER=%3
SET PASSWORD=%4
```

values which I want to set are DBNAME, DBSERVER, DBUSER and PASSWORDare parameters for batch file ?

Comment: What do you mean by hardcode the parameter values?

Comment: i want to set values for DBNAME, DBServer, DBUser, password

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just pass parameters to a batch file by appending them to the end of the file name, with a space between each parameter:

```
FOO.BAT NorthwindDB ServerName msbyuva 12345
```

And if you need to pass spaces in a parameter, just surround it in quotes:

```
FOO.BAT NorthwindDB "Server Name" msbyuva 12345
```

And if you need to remove those quotes in FOO.BAT you can use `~` notation:

```
set ServerName=%~2
```

Comment: Thank You LittleBobbyTables... I have never worked with batch files..thanks for your help..